# Wsdl returns null values in Csharp

Tags: web-services

I have a wsdl which is created in java, And gives response as class Array like MyBean[]. If i consume that wsdl in C#. It returns values as null. Whereas if i use the same wsdl in java project. It returns correct values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some sample code/data. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: And please edit your post to become a proper question. A good hint is: every question should end with a question mark.